# Simple site switcher

Tags: sites

This one has been asked many, many times but lots of the solutions are a bit over the top for me.

I have two sites: English and French. URLs are `mysite.com` and `mysite.com/fr`.

If I'm on `mysite.com/news/article-1` I want a simple link to `mysite.com/fr/news/article-1`, and vice versa.

The problem I have is getting the current URL after the language segment (ie I just want `news/article-1`). I would use `craft.app.request.url` but it includes the `fr` when on the French site.

Does anyone have a solution for this that doesn't involve about 20 lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's just something like this:

```
{% set enSite = craft.app.getSites().getSiteByHandle('en') %}
{% set frSite = craft.app.getSites().getSiteByHandle('fr') %}
{% set switchSiteUrl = currentSite.handle == 'en' ? frSite.baseUrl ~ craft.app.request.url|slice(1) : enSite.baseUrl ~ craft.app.request.url|slice(4)  %}
<a href="{{ switchSiteUrl }}">
  Other Site
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the translated version of the current entry, you can use the `localized` method:

```
{% set localizedEntry = entry.localized.one %}
<a href="{{ localizedEntry.url }}">{{ localizedEntry.site.name }}</a>
```

Or loop over `entry.localized.all()` if there are more than two sites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Trouble is, I'm not just using entries. There's routes and static templates too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you feel about plugins, but we've built one called [Site Switcher](https://plugins.craftcms.com/site-switcher) to do exactly this.

Using the plugin, it would look something like this...

```
{# Recognize translated slugs #}
{% set element = (category ?? entry ?? null) %}

{# Identify other site #}
{% set otherSite = currentSite.handle == 'en' ? 'fr' : 'en' %}

<a href="{{ siteSwitcher(otherSite, element) }}">
  Other Site
</a>
```